# Whether memcachedb is embedded?

Tags: java, oracle, memcached, berkeley-db, memcachedb

I read that `memcachedb` is using `berkley db as a storing backend`- [REF](http://memcachedb.org/). I read that `berkley db is embedded db`- [REF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database#Oracle_Berkeley_DB). But I am not able to find whether `memcachedb is embedded`. Any reference or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`memcachedb` is not embedded.  From your first reference, paragraph 1:

> It conforms to memcache protocol(not completed, see below), so any
>   memcached client can have connectivity with it.

Since it has a streaming protocol interface (over TCP/IP), it does not have to be embedded in your application like Berkeley DB.  It should be compatible with the `memcached's` protocol: https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt

Berkeley DB has a C API (or Java, or Python, etc.) and must be embedded into and managed by your application program.

Comment: @Gops AB - was this answer any help?